# Wordpress 500 Internal server error when activating custom theme

Tags: theme-development, themes, 500-internal-error

Whenever I try to activate my custom built theme on the clients server, the website returns a '500 - Internal Server Error'.

[image]

The theme is working fine on my local machine, MAMP on my mac. I dont even know where to begin to solve this problem!

As far as I am aware, the wordpress is a fresh install and I have no plugins that are activated.

**Edit:** As requested, here is the structure of my theme:

```
> theme-folder
  - 404.php
  > assets
    > css
    > font
    > images
    > js
    > sequence
  - category-food-and-baking.php
  - comments.php
  - footer.php
  - front-page.php
  - functions.php
  - header.php
  - index.php
  - page.php
  - sidebar.php
  - single-default.php
  - single-food-and-baking.php
  - single.php
  - style.css
```

And the first section of my CSS is:

```
/*
Theme Name: OonaghsKitchen
Theme URI: http://www.hknudsen.co.uk
Author:H Knudsen
Author URI: http://www.hknudsen.co.uk
Description: The theme for Oonaghs Kitchen
Version: 1
License: GNU General Public License v2 or later
License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
Tags: OonaghsKitchen
```

*/

Comment: Did you check your error logs?

Comment: Just to be clear, when you select a different theme, the issue is resolved? Can you share the file structure of your custom theme, and the head of your CSS file?

Comment: I'm struggling to locate the logs! I have never installed wordpress on a windows server before :/

Comment: Yes. The issue is resolved when I activate the 2013 default theme. I will update my post with the requested files in a second.

Comment: If you are on the dedicated server then check the apache/httpd/php log file. I am sure there you will find the reason of 500 error.
If you are on the shared server enable the WP debug mode then activate the theme if you are not getting the error then you can follow the below steps as well:
- Create sub directory in your root
- Do another WP fresh installation and activate the theme no other plugins.

Comment: @JonathanSampson, I have edited my post with the file structure and css head.

Answer (score 0):

You start by enabling [WP debugging](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress).

Wanted to add that a 500 error is typically a httpd server issue, either configuration or (more likely in this case) doing something in WP that you shouldnt, e.g. modifying http headers incorrectly.

Comment: I have set WP_DEBUG to true in the config, but nothing is being output to the page. The image in my post is the only error i can see.

Comment: I would enable WP_DEBUG and WP_DEBUG_LOG at a minimum so you can see what WP is doing via debug log file - /wp-content/debug.log